# Typescript generics constraint is not working

Tags: typescript

```
type PossibleValues = 'a' | 'b';
type Convert<T extends PossibleValues> = T extends 'a' ? string : number;

function myFunc<T extends PossibleValues>(param1: T): Convert<T> {
    if (param1 === 'a') {
        return 'someString'; // why can't I return a string?
    } else {
        return 0; // why can't I return a number?
    }
}

const testString = myFunc('a'); // type is string
const testNumber = myFunc('b'); // type is number
```

Typescript generic is not working in the above case. I'm trying to return string or number based on certain conditions, but ts throws error when returning.

What is strange is that variable such as testString and testNumber gets the correct type definition. Any help is appreciated

TS Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIDUCG6CuECUAvFAOQ7lQA%20Fq5A3AFCiRQDCcAdgG4QAnYAB4AKlAgAPYBG4ATYvCRpMuAkQB8pKOKkz5xStQD8UBMAHJuAcygAuKN3wBbVIJbMAZvm4BjYMg8UM4gAGI%20vmIS0rIKsIgoGNh4hAgaABRgOAI4zgCMDqIAlA5cfIIioloA3sxQ9VDInlCZ2bl5pCRkRkVQtQ0DUAIQwPgC3BQIcM4QAMoWVtZMUAD0K1AA7gAWIFC%20ONzkwFAAkkMjYxM4Zgs2xnUNAL4S6AjQ-YP1w6PjUAAMjFW622u32h2OZ2%20lyg1ycrkE9wGj2YyOYvh45igMnM80sNm0IXCfnSPUBayx4GgyGI5jx1jRGOO2OAADkXG4BASwhESQwimT1mwqcQ4RygA)

Comment: Typescript can't track relation between parameter and return type in function body. Easiest way to solve this - overloads. Problem that it won't validate that return value matches the parameter. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFwQBQAcCGATvsgIwBciA5PlQJSUDOUhMYA5gFCiSwIoYseIiQrUARvUpgQycQFNC3LHyRpMkYcTKUaVRAB8JUxM1YdDiGXMWIA3p0RPEMYIi2jEAXh-Vade0dnYMJ5KBBCJCpGOGR5AGUWNnYqAG4gpwBfRHkAG0Z5QOCQsIikAAZ04MzOGs4IBGZEKHlmRPN2bwENHD06VMQAekHm1FxCmEZTJI56xqhm1qgAOVkFQi71ISpJfqGRqDGJqet1oA